# How can I find the volume of a solid bounded by these functions?

Tags: calculus, volume

The region bounded by $x^2 - y = 0$ and $x+y=0$ is rotated around $y=0$

I've drawn a graph of each of these but I'm just not getting it conceptually. The biggest problem I have is knowing when to use the washer/disk/shell method.

Comment: Both will work, and are roughly equally pleasant.

Answer (score 1):

Using the washer method,

$$V=\int_{0}^{1} \pi \left( \sqrt{y}^2 - (-y)^2 \right) dy
\\ = \int_{0}^{1} \pi (y-y^2)dy$$

Imagine a paraboloid cup-like solid with vertex at the origin, pointing along the y-axis. Then imagine the inside of that cup being shaped like a cone. That's what this solid would look like. You would then use the washer method because the slices perpendicular to the x-axis are shaped like washers.